# Find maximum information using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a table X with the following structure in sql server 2008R2 db (there are >500k records):

[image: Table X]

Easy enough to find each UserAccountKey's maximum mx :

```
SELECT 
UserAccountKey
, MAX(mx) mx2
FROM X
GROUP BY UserAccountKey
```

But I'd like to amend the above so that it also has the SessionId and GamingServerId of the record(s) when the maximum occured.

Here's a work pad in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9e0a/1). The result I'm after is as follows

[image]

I'd rather not have to `JOIN` on mx if it can be avoided; so I assume a loop is the only way?

Comment: Unless your `mx` column has a unique index on it, you're going to have a hard time getting _accurate_ values for `SessionId` and `GamingServerId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`CTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) window-function:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT 
        RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY UserAccountKey ORDER BY mx DESC),
        UserAccountKey,
        SessionId, 
        GamingServerId,
        mx
    FROM X
)
SELECT  
    UserAccountKey,
    SessionId,
    GamingServerId,
    mx
FROM cte
WHERE RN = 1
```

Here's your fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9e0a/13

Comment: nice. If a player has two instances of the max mx how will this partition function behave?

Comment: @whytheq this looks a lot like a ranks, so you should be able to order it by a second column (ie. order by mx desc, SessionId).

Comment: You will always get exactly one record for each group. The order will be arbitrary. Note that you can specify more than one `ORDER BY` in `ROW_NUMBER`. Have a look here for the differences of the ranking function: http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.de/2008/10/difference-between-rownumber-rank-and.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a rank query:

```
select 
  UserAccountKey
  , SessionId
  , GamingServerId
  , mx
from (

SELECT
    rank() over (partition by UserAccountKey
                 order by mx desc) as rank
    , UserAccountKey
    , SessionId
    , GamingServerId
    , mx
FROM X )data
where rank = 1
```

This will basically Group everything by UserAccountkey, then order it by mx desc.
Then its just a question of selecting everything that has been given a rank of 1 (top value of mx for that UserAccountKey).

[My Fiddle results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9e0a/7)

Answer (score 1):

You need to first get the maximum record, then use that to get the other fields. Note that, if you have the same maximum twice for the same UserAccountKey, you'll get two records for that key.

```
select UserAccountKey, 
       SessionId, 
       GamingServerId, 
       mx
from x x1
where mx in
(SELECT MAX(mx) mx2
 FROM X x2
 WHERE x1.UserAccountKey = x2.UserAccountKey)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9e0a/20)

Comment: check the question out Allan - I'm trying not to Join on mx

Comment: @whytheq: Why not? In this case, the sub-query is run for each UserAccountKey and mx is only used to filter the results within that subset.

Comment: "Why not?" ...to be honest Allan after going away and coming back to this question I'm not sure! Your query has the definite advantage (=>+1) of pulling out all records that are tied highest - whereas the other answers that use `RANK` are only going to return one record per user.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
SELECT  UserAccountKey, SessionId, GamingServerId,mx 
FROM (SELECT UserAccountKey, SessionId, GamingServerId,mx, RANK()
      OVER (PARTITION BY UserAccountKey ORDER BY mx DESC) N
      FROM X
)M WHERE N = 1
```